# Just found my SD card was corrupted.

Tags: sd-card

Just found my SD card is corrupted.  My internal memory is almost full so was checking to see if it was going to the SD card yet and saw that it was corrupted.   Bought a new SD card. Now what do I do?  Can I just transfer the same memory into the new one?

Comment: Yes..you should

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide it is corrupted? When my phone can't read my SD card I usually do the following.

1. Insert the corrupted card in PC and blindly copy its content in some HD directory. I usually specify option ignore errors. It may cause issues with some files, but usually it is recoverable
2. I format the corrupted card with option check media for errors. If it got formatted with only few or no errors, I usually reuse it. Otherwise I take a new card
3. I copy all copied content from hard drive back to the new or old recovered card
4. I return the card back in the phone and usually it continues working as before

Note that SD card usually holds only certain number of rewrites, therefore if you do writing a lot, then a new card will be always a better solution.